# Neat/omega grid issue

Tags: sass, neat

I am very new to Neat and currently working on a simple grid that displays a gallery of images.

**My code**

```
$mobile: new-breakpoint(max-width 500px);
$tablet: new-breakpoint(max-width 768px);

article{
  background-color: #efefef;
  margin-bottom: 2em;

  @include span-columns(3);
  @include omega(4n);

  @include media($tablet){
    background-color: orange;
    @include span-columns(4);
    @include omega(3n);
  }

  @include media($mobile){
    background-color: yellow;
    @include span-columns(6);
    @include omega(2n);
  }
}
```

Now on desktop all shows as it should, but when I resize for **tablet** or **mobile**, the layout breaks and I get huge gaps in my layout... I know it's a silly little thing I am missing, but just can't see it ((( I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Omega can be a bit tricky with Neat. I would recommend using mutually-exclusive media queries to solve your problem, you can read more about them here:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/neat#how-do-i-use-omega-in-a-mobile-first-workflow

This stops the `omega` declarations persisting and breaking your layouts.

I would adjust your code so it looks like this:

```
$mobile: new-breakpoint(max-width 500px);
$tablet: new-breakpoint(min-width 501px max-width 768px);
$desktop: new-breakpoint(min-width 769px);

article{
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  @include media($mobile){
    background-color: yellow;
    @include span-columns(6);
    @include omega(2n);
  }

  @include media($tablet){
    background-color: orange;
    @include span-columns(4);
    @include omega(3n);
  }

  @include media($desktop){
    background-color: #efefef;
    @include span-columns(3);
    @include omega(4n);
  }
}
```

I have done a quick pen here so you can see it in action:

http://codepen.io/mikehdesign/pen/qajxrW

The height is just added to `article` for this example, it is not necessary if you have content in them.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! Thank you Mike! This did the trick, you can't imagine how much time I wasted trying to get it to work! Really appreciate it man, you're awesome :D